# Wordpress custom fields content don't appear when searched

Tags: wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I'm using the plugin Advanced Custom Fields on a custom post type. When I enter in content into the custom fields and publish, all looks fine BUT when trying to search for words that are in a custom field it doesn't show up...

I really need this content to be searchable.

I'm displaying the custom fields using this code

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'course-code', true); ?>
```

Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

Post meta is not included in WordPress default search. You could use a plugin like [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/), which extends WP's search functionality.